# Dropbear SSH server use-after-free vulnerability

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, ssh

"This vulnerability is located within the Dropbear daemon and occurs due
to the way the server manages channels concurrency. A specially crafted
request can trigger a `use after free` condition which can be used to
execute arbitrary code under root privileges provided the user has been
authenticated using a public key (authorized_keys file) and a command
restriction is enforced (command option).

Solution: Upgrade to version 2012.55 or higher."

http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Feb/403

Mercurial entry for the upgraded code: https://secure.ucc.asn.au/hg/dropbear/rev/818108bf7749

So does this means that I have to upgrade every dropbear on all my OpenWRT routers? What OpenWRT versions are affected??

Please help, it looks like an ASAP task!

Comment: Could you add some more details of the vulnerability in the text of your question?  Otherwise, it's fairly useless if the links ever die.

Comment: [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/ssh_configuration) is under active development. Last commit to dropbear was few days ago: https://github.com/lede-project/source/tree/master/package/network/services/dropbear The last build for x86_64 arch is dropbear_2017.75-2_x86_64.ipk 93.0 KB Sun Jun 18 14:58:13 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Open-WRT version is 2 years old now. If you have not upgraded individual services, then you will need to perform this upgrade.

From [Dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html):
"Security update 2012.55 — releases from 0.52 to 2011.54 are potentially vulnerable to code execution as root by an authenticated user if a command="..." option is used in authorized_keys. Release 2012.55 fixes the problem."

Also, consider switching to another router OS replacement that is under more active development, like [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).

Comment: "by an authenticated user" - so it's not a remote code execution, ok

Comment: Those appear reversed; it's OpenWrt that's in active development, while DD-WRT has stagnated. Though it may have been the other way round a year ago when you wrote this. The current release of OpenWrt, Attitude Adjustment, has dropbear 2012.55.